# getting Could not resolve placeholder while reading yml values in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, yaml

I'm using spring boot and using this value in my application.yml

```
config:
  username: abc
  password: xyz
```

In my class, I'm utilizing it this way -

```
@Value("${config.username}")
    private String username;
```

I'm getting the following error -

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'config.username' in value "${config.username}"
```

However if I use this in my application.yml file, it works. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
config.username: abc
config.password: xyz
```

Comment: Annoted the class with @Component.

Comment: Please check if your `class` that you are using `@Value` annotation has in `Spring Context`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check your placeholder is Tab or Space ? make sure no Tab in your yml file.

Comment: tried with spaces as well. also I validated my yml with validator but still no luck. :(  http://www.yamllint.com/

Answer (score 4):

was facing the same problem when trying to read from application.yml file instead of application.properties file. maven clean & then maven install resolved the issue for me.

Comment: had the same issue after upgrading spring boot to 3.1.0
mvn clean install worked for me, thx